# ifconfig wlan0 down in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, ifconfig

I am wondering how to use **ip** in ubuntu 17.10.

For instance, how we are going to implement the following down/up in ubuntu 17.10?

```
ifconfig wlan0 down/up
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ip link set wlp3s0 up
```

...or down, of course.

Please see: https://p5r.uk/blog/2010/ifconfig-ip-comparison.html